# unintelligable names in gprof

Tags: c, gprof

I am attempting to use [gprof](/questions/tagged/gprof) to profile a program that I have written, and am receiving unintelligible results.  Most of the function names are coming in like `_abfcd96687bed377dcecdf193c89698`.  I beleive that they are coming from a third party library that I am linking against, which I don't have source code for, so I can't recompile it for profiling.

I would like to understand where these functions are coming from, as one of them accounts for 17% of my running time, and I would like to see if I can reduce the number of calls to that as yet unknown function.

Comment: Don't expect gprof to answer that question for you. [*Here's what some people do.*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771)

Comment: @MikeDunlavey While investigating this, I found that answer of yours, which I found very interesting.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey When I actually attempted this, my first interrupted placed me in the function in question that takes up 17% of my running time.  Unfortunately my debugger only gave me about 3 levels of the call stack (possibly because that was all that was available in that thread).  I stepped through to find what function it was being called from, and in the time I was willing to spend (about 5 minutes), it did not leave that function.

Comment: Did you try to see the stack (command "bt")? That should show you the whole reason why you're spending the time, so maybe you can find a better way to accomplish the same thing. In my experience, it's a rare program that can't be sped up.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey I did use the backtrace functionality in my debugger (DDD).  It appears to not be able to cross thread boundries.

Comment: I use GDB, and you can say "thread n" to put it in whatever thread you want, then say "bt". Maybe DDD has something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to determine that the functions in question were part of the third party library using [callgrind](/questions/tagged/callgrind).

The raw `callgrind.out` file contains a listing of the functions in the program.  Included in this is what functions are called as a part of the running of each function.

Using this, I was able to trace up from the functions in question until I reached a function that is part of the library API.

As for the goal of optimization, the API function that is eating up most of my run time (>75%) cannot be called fewer times.  This is making it difficult (although not impossible) to spot other hotspots.